# How to iterate through the predicates in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog, but basically, I want a program to iterate through the predicates(not sure if I'm using that term correctly) and then come to a final predicate which can process the input and provide one of two answers. The ask and the maplist were my tries at iterating through the program the way a program like Java would. 
(Also, sidenote, but is there any way to have the user input Yes and No instead of true. and false.?)
Here's how my code looks currently:

```
ask(happy,X).
ask(lonely,X).
ask(education,X).
ask(institution,X).
ask(home,X).
ask(parents,X).
ask(social_life,X).
ask(hobbies,X).
ask(opinion,X).
ask(relationship,X).
ask(finances,X).
ask(future,X).
ask(freedom,X).
ask(feelings,X).

maplist(ask(_), Xs).


Xs= [happy(X),lonely(X),education(X),institution(X), home(X),
parents(X), social_life(X), hobbies(X), opinion(X), relationship(X),
finances(X), future(X), freedom(X),feelings(X)].

happy(X):-
     write("Are you happy?"),nl,
     read(X).

lonely(X):-
     write("Are you lonely?"),nl,
     read(X).
```

Comment: Hint: use a `main` predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can serve as inspiration

```
main(AnswersOut) :-
   Ls = [happy,lonely,education],
   ask_next_question(Ls,[],AnswersOut).

ask_next_question([L|Ls],Answers,AnswersOut) :-
   format("Question about: ~w\n",[L]),
   read_line_to_string(user_input,Str),
   format("You said: ~w\n",[Str]),
   ask_next_question(Ls,[L-Str|Answers],AnswersOut).

ask_next_question([],A,A).
```

Then you can collect answers into a list of pairs for further processing.
Note the use of [`read_line_to_string/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_line_to_string/2) which doesn't read a *term* (necessarily terminated with `.`) as [`read/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read/2) does, but an arbitrary String terminated by newline.

Run it:

```
?- main(A).
Question about: happy
|: Well....
You said: Well....
Question about: lonely
|: Yes
You said: Yes
Question about: education
|: Too high
You said: Too high
A = [education-"Too high", lonely-"Yes", happy-"Well...."].
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped me with 2 problems. Couple more, though:
You say I can collect the answers into a group of pairs for further processing, I assume using the ```Str```  variable. Got any ideas for the type of processing I could do(I was thinking Natural Language, but I doubt that's feasible.)
Also, is there a way I can process them to reach one of three verdicts at the end? Thanks.

Comment: @Biscuit In the example above, the `A` contains the responses for one user in the form of `Keyword-Value` pairs (which are just terms that actually look like `-(Keyword,Value)`). Your "verdict" predicates will have to examine the `A`. That's a possible processing btw. Collect many user responses (possibly storing them in the (volatile!) Prolog [database](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=db)) At the end, do stats with [library(aggregate)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)  on the Prolog toplevel